# How do I ensure only the headers are shown for the first item in an ItemsControl in WPF?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, styles, datatemplate, itemscontrol

I am using MVVM binding an `ObservableCollection` of children to an `ItemsControl`.  The `ItemsControl` contains a UserControl used to style the UI for the children.

```
<ItemsControl  ItemsSource="{Binding Documents}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>      
            <View:DocumentView Margin="0, 10, 0, 0" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

I want to show a header row for the contents of the `ItemsControl` but only want to show this once at the top (not for every child).  How can I implement this behaviour in the `DocumentView` user control?  Fyi I am using a `Grid` layout to `Style` the child rows:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="34"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="60" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />   
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.Row="0" Text="Should only show this at the top"></TextBlock>
    <Image Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Height="24" Width="24" Source="/Beazley.Documents.Presentation;component/Icons/error.png"></Image>        
    <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Name="ContentTypes" ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type View:MainView}}, Path=DataContext.ContentTypes}" SelectedValue="{Binding ContentType}"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Path=FileName}"/>
    <Button Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1"
        Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type View:MainView}}, Path=DataContext.RemoveFile}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding}">Remove</Button>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On second thoughts why are you even trying to do this yourself?

Looks like you are basically just trying to create a table with custom column types... Have you tried ListView or DataGrid controls?

Comment: Thanks, I switched to using a ListView.  I didn't realise you can style it as much as I needed.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think that's a nudge Dan ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the [AlternationCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.alternationcount.aspx) to work out the position of the item in your ItemsControl by setting the AlternationCount to the size of your collection.

Then apply your style only to the Item where ItemsControl.AlternationIndex = 0.

An example for a ListBox (which is an ItemsControl) assuming your collection is 5 in size:

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="alternatingWithTriggers" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
      <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
      <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="ListBox.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
          <Setter Property="Background" Value="CornflowerBlue"/>
          <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
        </Trigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

  </Grid.Resources>
  <ListBox AlternationCount="5" ItemsSource="{StaticResource data}" 
           ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource alternatingWithTriggers}">
  </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

There is no doubt a way to do it without triggers too...